# Exception thrown: read access violation. when accessing pointer in array

Tags: c++

I get an errors when trying to call a method in a class stored in collidersByLayer, this map is used to contain a vector of pointers, identified by the layer.

```
static map<int, vector<Collider*>> collidersByLayer;

//Called twice by both a player and a box
void AddCollider(Collider collider, int layer) {
    //outputs either 640 for the player or 840 for the box
    cout << collider.GetPosition().x << endl;

    //checks if a layer already exists, if not make a new entry in the map
    if (collidersByLayer.find(layer) == collidersByLayer.end()) {
        collidersByLayer[layer] = vector<Collider*>();
    }
    //add the reference to the collider
    collidersByLayer[layer].push_back(&collider);

    //loop through the collidersByLayer map
    for (auto const& x : collidersByLayer) {
        vector<Collider*> colliders = x.second;
        for (size_t c = 0; c < colliders.size(); c++) {
            //the first time this runs fine, and outputs the position of the player (640).
            //when this function is called for the second time,
            //it gives me this error while trying to print the players position:

            //Exception thrown: read access violation.
            //__imp_sf::Transformable::getPosition(...) returned 0x44520010.
            cout << colliders[c]->GetPosition().x << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `collidersByLayer[layer].push_back(&collider);` is pushing the address of `Collider collider` which is a local object into a static map. As soon as the function returns, that pointer is pointing to a destroyed object. There are several places in your example where you would benefit from using references. You should take a moment to read about [reference types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference). The intended usage of `AddCollider` isn't clear to me, so it's difficult to suggest a solution.

Comment: It is used to add a collider with a layer into collidersByLayer, so i can use this later on. The loop at the end was used for debug purposes.
Should i change the parameter to a reference instead of an object?

Comment: That depends on what you are trying to do. It sounds like the `Collider` already exists and you just want to add it's address to the map. In that case, yes making the function parameter a reference would help you. Then, the address you took at the `push_back` is that of the referred object. Beware though that you will have to make sure to remove that object's address from the map before it's lifetime ends. Let me know if this sounds like your situation so that I can post an answer.

Comment: Alright thank you very much! this is what i was looking for. If you post your answer i will accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is at the line `collidersByLayer[layer].push_back(&collider);` You are pushing the address of `Collider collider`, which is a local object, into a static map. Local objects are destroyed whenever the scope they belong to ends. In other words, as soon as the function returns, that pointer is pointing to a destroyed object. If you ever call `AddCollider` again, you will attempt to read from dangling pointer which is undefined behavior.

It sounds like the `Collider` objects already exists and you just want to add their addresses to your map. In that case, you can simply make your function's argument a reference type. By doing so, you will be getting the addresses of the referred objects instead of those of the local copies of those objects. Try the following :

```
void AddCollider(Collider & collider, int layer)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here:

```
collidersByLayer[layer].push_back(&collider);
```

You are adding a pointer to a local variable to the collection. That object is destroyed when `AddCollider` returns.